# Enable Trace Log Level

Tags: java, logging, netty, slf4j

i have slf4j version 1.7.5. 
How do i make log.trace() work such that isTraceEnabled() will return true.

Also I have already added to my pipeline the following code:

```
pipeline.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE));
```

Answer (score 1):

Slf4j is just a layer on top of an underlying logging system. `log.isTraceEnabled()` will return true if logging is enabled in the underlying logger for the underlying logger's equivalent of the trace level. So, you need to configure the real logging system to do trace-level logging for the relevant logger.

Comment: how do i configure the real logging system?

Comment: What _is_ the real logging system?

Comment: i have a problem identifying the real logging system. i want to enable trace log level for the [netty socketio library](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/)

Comment: Socketio uses slf4j, which is just a layer on top of another logging system as I said. What environment is this code running in? If it's an application server like Tomcat or JBoss, the app server provides the logging system.